# I have a couple preg_replace unknown modifiers warnings on a string and I don't know the regex fix

Tags: php, regex, wordpress

I have a string that's throwing up a couple php errors.

I'm using some regex to strip `<p>` tags from images and iframes.

I'm also using regex to replace a `<br\>` with two `<br\><br\>`.

I'm using it on `$content` in wordpress.

It's throwing an error and therefore nothing is being returned in `the_content();`

If I remove the functions the content appears fine, though without the formatting changes.

I assume if I fix these errors the content will work fine but I don't know how to adjust the regex.

Anyway here are the errors:

```
[12-Aug-2014 19:46:46 UTC] PHP Warning:  preg_replace(): Unknown modifier '&gt;' in /functions.php on line 101
[12-Aug-2014 19:46:46 UTC] PHP Warning:  preg_replace(): Unknown modifier 'f' in /functions.php on line 102
[12-Aug-2014 19:46:46 UTC] PHP Warning:  preg_replace(): Unknown modifier '?' in /functions.php on line 133
```

And of course the code:

```
function filter_ptags($content){
    $content = preg_replace('/<p>s*(<a .*>)?s*(<img .* />)s*(</a>)?s*</p>/iU', '123', $content);
    return preg_replace('/<p>s*(<iframe .*>*.</iframe>)s*</p>/iU', '1', $content);
}
function strip_content($content){
    $content = preg_replace(array('/(<brs*/?>s*){1,}/'), array('<br/><br/>'), $content);
}
```

I really need to spend some time getting a grasp on regex...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You need to escape `/` in a regex expression. It should be `\/`
- It should be `\s*` instead of `s*` to match zero or more white spaces.

Change:

```
(<brs*/?>s*){1,}
```

To:

```
(<br\s*\/?>\s*){1,}
```

Here is [online demo](http://regex101.com/r/oR3aU8/1) where you can validate your regex expression as well.

Comment: ah that worked, what about the first two regex lines?

Comment: make both changes as mentioned above and test it at the above mentioned site. If still there is any issue then share some inputs.

Comment: Try `<p>\s*(<a .*>)?\s*(<img .* \/>)\s*(<\/a>)?\s*<\/p>` for first one and `<p>\s*(<iframe .*>*.<\/iframe>)\s*<\/p>` for second one